# Connect Window Form server with an asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, database, winforms, synchronization

I have a c# window form application (which is basically a game).

And an ASP.NET Website. the window form application has a database with a table that contains the username and his cash. The asp.net database has a table that contains the username and his cash.

Now I want to sync between to the two servers. Once I get point in my game, It'll also update the database of the asp.net site.

Comment: You should rephrase your question and call the Windows Forms application "client".

Comment: I'm guessing the earned 'Cash' can also be spent in the game? And is the game playable while there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose a web service endpoint in the web app which the Windows app can call to post updated user stats.

Likewise a web service could return updated stats to the Windows client for synchronization into the Windows app database.

As [Uwe Keim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) mentions, the web app can only expose a service or data feed that the Windows client must poll regularly. There is no feasible way that the web app can call the Windows app directly.

Comment: It should be noted, that the server cannot directly send data to the client, but only, as you said, be polled for data in regular intervals (by calling SOAP functions) and then return a value to the calling client.

Answer (score 2):

Why not host the database on one location and let the game/website connect to your DB through a web service? This way you only need one database with all the relevant data compared to two. You'll have to recode some parts of your website and game but in the long run this is more optimal than two databases with the same data.

More information regarding web services can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: A possibly broken internet connection is probably why the OP want to store the stats offline anyway, thus synchronization is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop some kind of an API (Service) in the web application and do the sync between the two apps. You are talking about two servers at the end of your post. What kind of servers are you talking about? Is the game available in standalone also? If not, can't you think of having a single DB for both of them?